# What is the best way to pass values from jsp to controller in Spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp page that is dynamic configured. By different choice, the page has different components, just like dropdown list, list box and datetime etc. For one choice, the page may have only two dropdown list, and by another choice, the page has more enter field. Each enter field has different name. Even one page has two dropdown lists, the two lists have different names. 
Just want to get your suggestion, what is the best way to get all these values to controller in Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

- JSP: enclose all the input fields (textbox/select/checkbox/radio) in `<FORM>` tags and set the action attribute of the form to call the Controller.
- Controller:

  - Define a simple Java bean class with attributes corresponding to each of the input field in the form
  - Accept this class type as a parameter to the method in the controller that will be called upon `<FORM>` submission and annotate the parameter with `@RequestBody`.

See [Mapping the response body with the @ResponseBody annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) for more details on completing the wiring.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But one problem is that all fields' name in jsp are not pre-defined. And the name of the input field are generated by another logic dynamically. so no bean can handle this situation. I wish to get a solution to automatically find all input fields in the jsp and pass the values to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a DTO to hold all possible form element

   ```
   Class MyFormData {
     private String name;
     private Double salary;
     private List<String> hobbies;
     ......
   }
   ```
2. In controller, use `@ResponseBody`

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public void handle(@RequestBody MyFormData formData, Model model) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If your UI is so dynamic, you might as well bite the bullet and go for a Javascript solution. Spring MVC will simply receive and return JSON as @RequestBody and @ResponseBody and not worry so much about the fundamental MVC.

JSP can only get you so far in terms of dynamic UI behavior. Once you get comfortable with JQuery and/or AngularJS, you'll never look back.